# How to delete all objects from a folder/directory in open stack swift using rest api?

Tags: api, openstack, openstack-swift, object-storage

I want to delete all files and folders using folder or container path without listing all files in it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Note that with more recent versions of openstack, there is a `--recursive` option available if you're deleting any entire container:

```
openstack container delete --recursive mycontainer
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible from API?

Comment: The CLI tools interact with Swift using the API, so it must be. If you run the above command with `--debug` enabled, you can see the API calls the tool is making.

Answer (score 2):

You use the following 2 steps method based on swift package (https://launchpad.net/swift) - Successfully tested on debian jessie

In a terminal, once swift tool configurated, type :

*# swift list  | grep  > yourobjectname.lst*

*# cat yourobjectname.lst | xargs swift delete  {}*

Regards

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible with the [OpenStack API](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref.html) that comes out-of-the-box. You need to *explicity* list the objects/containers and delete them using the [bulk operation](https://swiftstack.com/docs/admin/middleware/bulk.html#bulk-delete)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following command as said in [this](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/89512/remove-all-empty-containers-in-one-go-swift/) QA:

```
for i in $(swift list); do swift delete $i; done
```

Note that you need to have your environment variables for the user and project and domain set before running this command. e.g. `admin-rc.sh`